# ¿Cómo usar una variable para inicializar un array de String?

Tags: array

Quiero inicializar un `array` de `String` con un tamaño sacado de una variable, pero me da el error:

> Illegal array bound for: denominaciones

Este es el código:

```
Dim size As Integer
size =  vista.EntryCount 'return Integer'
Dim denominaciones( size ) As String
```

Si en vez de poner la variable `size` pongo un valor numérico como `100` funciona.

```
Dim denominaciones( 100 ) As String
```

He probado a poner:

```
Dim denominaciones( 1 to size) As String
```

Pero nada...

También he probado a inicializar el `array` y después redimensionarlo con `Redim` pero tampoco.

**¿Cómo puedo poner una variable como tamaño para el array?**

Comment: lois6b, el ReDim hace exactamente eso, Re dimensionar la definición de una variable, por eso debes primero dimensionarla y posteriormente re dimensionarla. Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con `Redim` si funciona, al menos con este ejemplo que acabo de realizar. Lo que si hay que tener en cuenta es que las declaraciones de los arrays no se pueden hacer de forma dinámica, necesitan una connotación literal (string, integer, variant, etc.).

Es decir, podemos declarar el array sin un límite (aunque tiene límite) y luego redimensionarlo.

Te pongo el ejemplo que acabo de hacer y que funciona perfectamente.

```
Dim vector As Integer

vector = 10

Dim array() As Variant

Redim array(vector)

array(0) = "Hola Mundo"

Msgbox array(0)
```

Comment: funciona perfecto, gracias . pero mirando la documentación, no veo que haya que hacer `Dim` vacio y luego un `Redim`.